# Calling a Javascript function with parameters from JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, liferay, alloy-ui

I have a form like this...

```
<aui:form action="<%= generateRuleURL.toString() %>" name="rulesForm" method="post">
<aui:button-row>
<aui:button type="button" id="End" value="End"  />
<aui:button type="button" id="And" value="And" />
<aui:button type="button" id="Or" value="Or" />
</aui:button-row>
</aui:form>
```

In a view jsp file.

And a JS like this...

```
document.getElementById( 'End' ).onclick = function()
{
    var x=document.forms["rulesForm"]["FirstRuleElement"].value;
    System.out.println("Prova : " + x);
    var y=document.forms["rulesForm"]["FirstRuleAttribute"].value;
    System.out.println("Prova : " + y);
    var z=document.forms["rulesForm"]["Operator"].value;
    System.out.println("Prova : " + z);
    alert("First name must be filled out");

    if (x==null || x=="" || y==null || y=="" || z==null || z=="")
    {
      alert("First name must be filled out");
      return false;
    }

    AUI().one("#<portlet:namespace/>rulesForm").action='<%= generateRuleURL.toString()%>';

    document.forms["rulesForm"].submit();
};
```

In `submit.js` file.

What I should do for calling this method from one of the buttons, and other methods for the others? I tried lot of thinks but this didn't function..

**For example:**

Calling a commonFunction `js: onclick="commonFunction('End')"` //End is a string to be passed as a parameter

and so on.. with no results!

Could someone give me a hand with this?

Comment: Note that you're using `document.forms["rulesForm"]` as well as `AUI().one("#<portlet:namespace/>rulesForm")`, also you're using ids that might conflict with other ids on the same page: In a portlet you never know whom you share the page with (it might be the same portlet deployed twice), so you always should disambiguate HTML-ids with `<portlet:namespace/>`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways you can do what you want to:

1. One way is to put your javascript code in the `view.jsp` and use `<portlet:namespace/>` like this:

   ```javascript
   <aui:script>
   document.getElementById('<portlet:namespace/>End').onclick = function()
   {
       var x=document.forms["<portlet:namespace/>rulesForm"]["<portlet:namespace/>FirstRuleElement"].value;
       System.out.println("Prova : " + x);
       var y=document.forms["<portlet:namespace/>rulesForm"]["<portlet:namespace/>FirstRuleAttribute"].value;
       System.out.println("Prova : " + y);
       var z=document.forms["<portlet:namespace/>rulesForm"]["<portlet:namespace/>Operator"].value;
       System.out.println("Prova : " + z);
       alert("First name must be filled out");

       if (x==null || x=="" || y==null || y=="" || z==null || z=="")
       {
         alert("First name must be filled out");
         return false;
       }

       AUI().one("#<portlet:namespace/>rulesForm").action='<%= generateRuleURL.toString()%>';

       document.forms["<portlet:namespace/>rulesForm"].submit();
   };
   </aui:script>
   ```

   We need to use `<portlet:namespace/>` since you are using liferay's `aui` tags like `<aui:form>` which prepends the `<portlet:namespace/>` to the `name` and `id` attribute.
   Also using `<portlet:namespace/>` ensures that `id` or `name` attributes of elements does not conflict with other elements on the page as mentioned by @OlafKock in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295260/calling-a-javascript-function-with-parameters-from-jsp#comment23326411_16295260).
2. Another way, if you want to use the javascript file `submit.js` then create a javascript `function` in that file:

   ```javascript
   function submitMyForm(portletNamespace) {

       var x=document.forms[portletNamespace + "rulesForm"][portletNamespace + "FirstRuleElement"].value;
       System.out.println("Prova : " + x);
       var y=document.forms[portletNamespace + "rulesForm"][portletNamespace + "FirstRuleAttribute"].value;
       System.out.println("Prova : " + y);
       var z=document.forms[portletNamespace + "rulesForm"][portletNamespace + "Operator"].value;
       System.out.println("Prova : " + z);
       alert("First name must be filled out");

       if (x==null || x=="" || y==null || y=="" || z==null || z=="")
       {
         alert("First name must be filled out");
         return false;
       }

       AUI().one("#<portlet:namespace/>rulesForm").action='<%= generateRuleURL.toString()%>';

       document.forms[portletNamespace + "rulesForm"].submit();
   }
   ```

   Call this function from the `view.jsp` as:

   ```jsp
   <aui:form action="<%= generateRuleURL.toString() %>" name="rulesForm" method="post">
       <aui:button-row>
           <aui:button type="button" id="End" value="End" onClick="submitMyForm('<portlet:namespace/>')" />
           <aui:button type="button" id="And" value="And" />
           <aui:button type="button" id="Or" value="Or" />
       </aui:button-row>
   </aui:form>
   ```

Hope this helps in going forward.